# Custom hardcoded functions : in node.tpl.php or theme_preprocess_node?

Tags: 7, theming, performance

For a specific content type, I have many hardcoded functions, to format, display my content, use some ajax, JS, etc.

I was wondering, for **performance**, **scalability** and, more globally, **best practice**, if my functions should be all in **node--mycontenttype.tpl.php or in mytheme_preprocess_node**.

I actually began my coding with that last solution and I'm kind of worried about performance and other matters.

Do you have an advice ?

Thank you.

Comment: Preprocess functions == logic/functionality. Template files == markup/printing variables (_that have been set up in a preprocess function_). Remember that and you'll go far :)

Comment: Thx Clive :) In that sense, where do I put i.e a rendered view ?

Comment: Pass it through to whatever template from a preprocess function, e.g. `$vars['some_view'] = views_embed_view('name', 'display', $arg);` then `<div id="the-view"><?php echo $some_view; ?></div>` in the template file :) The classic example of what not to put in a template file is a call to `drupal_add_css()`, as the aggregator won't pick that up and it will result in unnecessary HTTP requests. Putting logic in the template file also messes up caching in a lot of instances

Comment: Great ! Thx very much.